# Adding Category Attribute to Select

Tags: category, attributes, collection, category-tree, category-attribute

I'm trying to add a custom category attribute to the category collection:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setId($productId);
$categories = $product->getResource()
    ->getCategoryCollection($product)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('some_custom_attribute');
```

However, `some_custom_attribute` doesn't get included to the collection data:

```
[4] => array(11) {
["entity_id"] => string(4) "1164"
["entity_type_id"] => string(1) "3"
["attribute_set_id"] => string(1) "3"
["parent_id"] => string(4) "1151"
["created_at"] => string(19) "2015-04-14 06:19:05"
["updated_at"] => string(19) "2015-04-14 06:19:05"
["path"] => string(13) "1/2/1151/1164"
["position"] => string(1) "3"
["level"] => string(1) "3"
["children_count"] => string(1) "0"
["product_id"] => string(6) "106224"
```

How can I add the `some_custom_attribute` to the result?

Comment: If some_custom_attribute is a new attribute, you need to rebuild the category flat index before it is included in collections

Answer (score 2):

try this code (it works for me)

```
$_categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sales_page_active_from',true)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sales_page_active_to',true)
            ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is not working. So you can ***use below code as alternatively***.

> ```
> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
> $product->setId($productId);
> ```

***Get category ids of product***

> ```
> $CategoryIds = $product->getResource()
>     ->getCategoryIds($product);
> ```

***Load category collection***

> `$collection= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');`

***Add filter category collection by categories ids***

> `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => implode(',',$CategoryIds)));`

***Add a custom category attribute to the category collection:***

> `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('some_custom_attribute');`

Comment: Unfortunately, the attribute is not displayed or added. I tried to add a system default attribute, no luck.